# Is it possible to have multiple GoogleApiClients within one activity?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, google-play-services, google-places-api

I'm trying to make a business search app that is location aware. To do this I'm using Google Places Api, specifically Places.GEO_DATA_API and LocationServices.API. The idea is that the user can use their current location or use the autoComplete search to input an address. My problem is that I think the two apis are getting mixed up when calling `onConnected()` since I keep getting this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: edu.depaul.csc472.coffeeshoplocator, PID: 9420
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzrb.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzrf.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzrd.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
                      at edu.depaul.csc472.coffeeshoplocator.MainActivity.startLocationUpdates(MainActivity.java:233)
                      at edu.depaul.csc472.coffeeshoplocator.MainActivity.getLocation(MainActivity.java:241)
                      at edu.depaul.csc472.coffeeshoplocator.MainActivity.onConnected(MainActivity.java:263)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk.zzp(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzrd.zzn(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzrb.zzass(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzrb.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzrf.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqr.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$1.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze$zzj.zzavj(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze$zza.zzv(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze$zze.zzavl(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

It only happens sometimes. I've successfully ran the program without any unexpected behavior except for this crash.

The code for building the apis is the following:

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
        mGoogleApiLocation = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
         mGoogleApiAutoComplete = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                 .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                 .enableAutoManage(this,GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID,this)
                 .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                 .build();
    }
```

And here is my `onConnected()` method which requests permission to access fine location from the user and then attempts to get the location of the user:

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        requestForSpecificPermission();
        getLocation();
        placeArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(mGoogleApiAutoComplete);

    }
```

...and my `getLocation()` method:

```
private void getLocation(){
        try {
            location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiLocation);
            if (location == null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiLocation, locationRequest, this);
            }
            else{
                handleNewLocation(location);
            }
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "You don't have permission!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

My curiosity is one: how am I getting that error if from my understanding you have to be connected to call `onConnected()` and two: why does this only happen some of the times. Is having multiple clients allowed in the first place or if not how do you go about using two different technologies(apis) in the same activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do `implements ConnectionCallbacks` in your `Activity`/`Fragment` and try the following:

```
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks mGoogleApiLocationCallback = new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }
    };

    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks mGoogleApiAutoCompleteCallback = new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }
    };
```

And then change your method like this:

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
    mGoogleApiLocation = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(mGoogleApiLocationCallback)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiAutoComplete = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(mGoogleApiAutoCompleteCallback)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this,GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID,this)
            .build();
}
```

Just make sure to remove `implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` from your `Activity`/`Fragment`

Comment: I'm not crazy though right...that is probably where the bug was. There was a conflict between the two APIs before but you can have more than one. It's not crashing anymore but like I said it only did that occasionally.

Comment: It will be a problem if two different Clients are trying to use the same callback. So having completely separate client for each should do the job. Still weird that it was occasionally